# Synchronizing calls to nested asynchrounous functions with dispatch_sync and dispatch_async

Tags: objective-c, asynchronous, synchronization, grand-central-dispatch

I have a method which runs asynchronously and returns results through a completion handler. The method call itself returns "immediately" but the completion handler can take some time to be called.

I would like to serialize calls to this method such that it will not run twice if the completion handler hasn't been handled in the previous call.

Right now I am using a flag

```
-(void)myAsyncMethod:(void(^)(NSError *error))block
{
  if(_isRunning) 
  {
     return; // would like to queue the call
  }
  _isRunning = YES;
  // do some long running async work which themselves can have completion handlers and run asynchronously

  // look for ever place with a call to "block"

  _isRunning = NO;
  block(error); 
}
```

Is there a way to do this without using flags inside the method call using dispatch_sync,async etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to create a serial dispatch queue once:

```
self.serialQueue = dispatch_queue_create("identifier", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
```

and submit a block for asynchronous execution on that queue:

```
- (void)myAsyncMethod:(void(^)(NSError *error))block
{
    dispatch_async(self.serialQueue, ^{
        NSError *error;
        // long running task ...
        block(error);
    });
}
```

**UPDATE:** After reading your question again, I realized that the above method does not
work if the "long running task" itself works asynchronously with completion handlers.

To cover that situation, you can use a "dispatch group":

```
self.group = dispatch_group_create();

-(void)myAsyncMethod:(void(^)(NSError *error))block
{
    dispatch_async(self.serialQueue, ^{
        // Start job:
        dispatch_group_enter(self.group);
        NSError *error;

        [self longRunningTaskWithCompletionHandler:^(void){
            block(error);
            // Signal that job is done:
            dispatch_group_leave(self.group);
        }];

        // Wait until job is done:
        dispatch_group_wait(self.group, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
    });
}
```

(Alternatively, one could use a "dispatch semaphore".)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, what you're doing is already the simplest method.  You don't need any additional queues or groups or semaphores or, well, **anything** other than exactly what you are doing!

To answer the implicit question, there is nothing wrong with checking internal state flags - that's how cancellation works, in fact.  If you want to be able to cancel something after it's been put on a queue, you'd better have a method you can call (right away, not enqueued) that sets an internal "is_cancelled" flag that you then check right at the beginning of the work block/function and choose to simply return straight-away if it's set.  There's no magic bullet for cancellation, just as there's no magic bullet for "don't run me twice if the body of my work hasn't completed yet" - what you're doing is essentially equivalent to cancellation, you're just "canceling" the subsequent calls while the first one is still working.

Comment: It seems that we understood the question differently. From the comment  *"would like to queue the call"* in the code I assumed that a second call should not be just cancelled if the previous one is still running, but enqueued and run after the previous call has completed. That's why I suggested the more complicated code.

Comment: I think the question is somewhat ambiguous as worded.  Who's to say whether or not **either** of us understood it properly. :)